# how to process text timestamp in hive

Tags: hive

I have a column in hive table stored as text. The text looks as shown below

> 2007-01-01T00:00:00+00:00

I am trying to find difference in time between two timestamp value stored as text in the above format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we've got an Hive table **dateTest** with two column **date1** string, **date2** string
and suppose that table containing a row with this values:

2007-01-01T00:00:00+00:00,2007-02-01T00:00:00+00:00

The dates are in ISO 8601 UTC format, so if you run this query:

```
select datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date2, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")),from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))) as days
from datetest;
```

the result is 31